# Branch Remote Run Trigger doesn't run on Teamcity

Tags: .net, git, testing, continuous-integration, teamcity

**Goal**: I try to create a Pre-Tested Commits approach (first run CI build with tests, next push them to "green" repository if OK)

**Problem:** the Branch Remote Run Trigger doesn't work and TeamCity server doesn't pull changes to run the build. I can't understand why is so and how to fix it.

**Description:**

I have two configurations in one TC project. Both of them watches the same git repository but different branches(as default). There are total 3 branches: master (not used here), develop (for working builds and green tests) and artemPersonal(for personal builds)

1. WebUI Develop. Uses refs/heads/develop branch only for green repository. New commits comes to this branch from TC after successful personal builds.
2. WebUI Develop Pre-Tested Commits. Uses
   refs/heads/artemPersonal  as default branch

   2.1 I have a set Branch Remote Run Trigger with path to branch: `refs/heads/artemPersonal`  I tried different variations like
   `refs/heads/*`.

   2.2 I have a set VCS root with default  branch: `refs/heads/artemPersonal` And empty Branch specification. I also tried to fill branc specification with some values, but now it's empty.

I push to `refs/heads/artemPersonal` and expect  TC to run Remote-Run trigger  to pull changes and start next build. It doesn't. The pending changes appears on UI of TC but build doesn't start. Manually works fine.

the teamcity-remote-run.log file give such messages:

> Branch 'refs/heads/artemPersonal' in VCS root '"WebSite Development
>   Pre-tested Commits" **is matched by branchSpec, branch will be ignored**

and

> First run of the trigger for buildType 'WebSite :: WebUI develop
>   Pre-Tested Commits **3 branch(es) matched by the pattern. New commits or
>   new matched branches will trigger a personal build**.

**P.S.** I know the workaround not to use personal builds and Branch Remote Run Trigger and use simple VCS Trigger and check `artemPersonal` branch only. But I want to use Personal builds.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I run TeamCity 8 and I'm not able to get the build configurations to detect any of the branches that I create (I've used the default 'refs/heads/remote-run/*' following the simple steps in the documentation).

Comment: no, I didn't. It was so long about, that I don't remeber the workaround.

Comment: You shouldn't leave it at 'refs/heads/remote-run/*' unless your branch names actually have that in there. For instance, we require branch names to be `users/userName/BranchName` so the value in the trigger is: ''refs/heads/users/*'.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the branch you're using for personal build is refs/heads/artemPersonal. 
It should not appear in the Default branch or Branch specification list in the VCS Root.

In order to run a personal build you need to define a trigger on each build configuration you want to use. (e.g. Pattern of Branches to Monitor = refs/heads/*). In your case you can use WebUI Develop.

Make sure that you have the same username in Team city and Git.